# How to scan this input?

Tags: c++, vector, input

I have a integer number say 1234.I want to store it digit by digit in a vector.
So i wrote the following

```
vector<int>arr;
        int c;
   while(cin>>c)
        {
            arr.push_back(c);
        }
```

But this is taking `1234`as a whole an passing onto the vector.I don't want to use `gets()` and all the other functions which scan the digit as a character.So is there any way to do it?

Comment: Learn what the modulo operation does and how to use it.

Comment: Use [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) to peel off one character at a time. By default this will try and read a whole integer value.

Comment: Consider treating the number as a group of characters.  Isolating digits is usually easier as a string of characters than a number.